# How do i get active minutes?

Tags: jawbone

I am trying to get active minutes out of Jawbone API's but haven't find anything. Is there a way to get to know active minutes of a user? Does jawbone supports and shows active minutes?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation for the [moves endpoint](https://jawbone.com/up/developer/endpoints/moves). One of the pieces of data that comes back for a move event is `active_time`, which is the total active time in seconds.

[image: active_time definition]

Comment: thanks ! but does this active time is the uninterrupted time of the activity done or it is the sum of all the times for which user was performing some activity? e.g. I am running on treadmill for 15 mins. But i took a break after 5 mins and rest for 3 mins and then again run on treadmill for 7 mins. In this case the Active time will be 12 mins or 15 mins? pls confirm.

Comment: It's sum of all the active times in the time period.